# Electric behaviour for existing parentheses

Tags: math-mode, emacs, auctex

I have enabled
    `(LaTeX-electric-left-right-brace)` 
in AUCTeX.
Thus, when I type `\bigl(`, the corresponding closing `\bigr)` is automatically inserted.

Suppose that I already have written `(foo)` and now decide that I want to use big parentheses.

How can I make AUCTeX insert the matching `\bigr` when I insert `\bigl`?

1. I have `(foo)`
2. I insert `\bigl`, thus I get `\bigl(foo)`.
3. AUCTeX shall now automatically produce `\bigl(foo\bigr)`.

Of course it should insert the `\bigr` at the matching parentheses.
If I have `(foo(bar))`, then `\bigl(foo(bar)\bigr)` should be produced.

Comment: I think it's probably more bother to get the behaviour you want than just to do this by hand the few times it comes up. [Relevant xkcd.](https://xkcd.com/1205/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up doing things a bit different.

I defined a kbd-macro and saved it to my init.el (see https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Save-Keyboard-Macro.html). (Add this to your init.el)

```
(fset '\bigl1
   [?\\ ?b ?i ?g ?l ?\C-\M-n left ?\\ ?b ?i ?g ?r right ?\C-\M-p])
```

Then I bounded it to some keyboard command (add this to your init.el)

```
(eval-after-load 'latex 
  '(define-key LaTeX-mode-map (kbd "s-1")  #'bigl1))
```

So pressing `s-1` (windowskey (on most machines) together with 1) produces `\bigl(foo\bigl)` if we had `(foo)` (and cursor at the left parentheses).

To get this behaviour as well for `Bigl` and `biggl` I ended up with

```
(fset '\bigl1
      [?\\ ?b ?i ?g ?l ?\C-\M-n left ?\\ ?b ?i ?g ?r right ?\C-\M-p])
(fset '\bigl2
      [?\\ ?B ?i ?g ?l ?\C-\M-n left ?\\ ?B ?i ?g ?r right ?\C-\M-p])
(fset '\bigl3
      [?\\ ?b ?i ?g ?g ?l ?\C-\M-n left ?\\ ?b ?i ?g ?g ?r right ?\C-\M-p])
(eval-after-load 'latex 
  '(define-key LaTeX-mode-map (kbd "s-1")  #'bigl1))
(eval-after-load 'latex 
  '(define-key LaTeX-mode-map (kbd "s-2")  #'bigl2))
(eval-after-load 'latex 
  '(define-key LaTeX-mode-map (kbd "s-3")  #'bigl3))
```

in my init.el file. (first)

Then I programmed a bit around and now I can add (by pressing 
`s-1`, `s-2`, `s-3`, `s-4`) `\bigl/\bigr`, `\Bigl/\Bigr`, `\biggl/\biggr`, `\Biggl/\Biggr` to the next(right of the coursor) `(,),[,],\{,\}` and its counterpart to the matching `),(,],[,\},\{`

```
(defun addthings-left-right-latex-parentheses (links rechts)
  "Adds first Input to the left and the second Input 
   to the right of the next  (,),[,],\{,\} (right of the coursor)
   to the matching ),(,],[,\},\{"
  (interactive "sWhat do you want left of parentheses?:
   \nsWhat do you want right of parentheses?: ")  
  (when (re-search-forward "[][()]\\|\\\\[{}]")
(if (or (char-equal (char-before) ?\() (char-equal (char-before) ?\[))
    (progn (backward-char)
       (insert links)
       (forward-list)
       (backward-char)
       (insert rechts))
  (if (or (char-equal (char-before) ?\)) (char-equal (char-before) ?\]))
      (progn
    (backward-list)
    (insert links)
    (forward-list)
    (backward-char)
    (insert rechts))
      (if (char-equal (char-before) ?\{)
      (progn
        (backward-char)(backward-char)
        (insert links)
        (forward-char)(forward-char)
        (setq counter 1)      
        (while  (< 0 counter)
          (progn
        (re-search-forward "\\\\[{}]")
        (if (char-equal (char-before) ?\{)
          (setq counter (+ counter 1))
          (setq counter (+ counter -1)))))
        (backward-char)(backward-char)
        (insert rechts))
    (progn
      (backward-char)(backward-char)
      (insert rechts)
      (setq counter 1)    
        (while  (< 0 counter)
          (progn
        (re-search-backward "\\\\[{}]")
        (forward-char)
        (if (char-equal (char-after) ?\})
          (setq counter (+ counter 1))
          (setq counter (+ counter -1)))))
        (backward-char)
        (insert links)))))))
(eval-after-load 'latex 
  '(define-key LaTeX-mode-map (kbd "s-1")
 (lambda () (interactive)
   (addthings-left-right-latex-parentheses "\\bigl" "\\bigr"))))
(eval-after-load 'latex 
  '(define-key LaTeX-mode-map (kbd "s-2")
 (lambda () (interactive)
   (addthings-left-right-latex-parentheses "\\Bigl" "\\Bigr"))))
(eval-after-load 'latex 
  '(define-key LaTeX-mode-map (kbd "s-3")
 (lambda () (interactive)
   (addthings-left-right-latex-parentheses "\\biggl" "\\biggr"))))
(eval-after-load 'latex 
  '(define-key LaTeX-mode-map (kbd "s-4")
 (lambda () (interactive)
   (addthings-left-right-latex-parentheses "\\Biggl" "\\Biggr"))))
```

So there are no more excuses for not making your (mathematical) latex-parentheses more readable.